Running several python functions in parallel using slurm from a central python script
I am running a python script on a HPC facility with slurm as the workload manager. In the script, I have a list of say 10,000 different object instances with an id in a dictionary of the form:
d = {id1 : instance1, ...}
This central script will determine which ids (around 100) are selected to perform calculations. A calculation is performed when calling:
d[idx].calculate()
In the background, this will set up a calculation (prepare input files) and run the command line command:
mpirun -np <num_cores> calc_executable.exe
The executable uses mpi but this does not need to be configured, only the number of cores <num_cores> needs to be set. This calculation may take a long time (maybe 24 hours). All calculations are independent all may run on different a number of cores. Once it is finished, the outputs will be collected and the object instance d[id] is updated with the result of the calculation (one of the attributes is assigned a value).
Note that I could change the code so that I call the command line command directly and set up all input files myself. This is not preferred but would be ok if it makes the interaction with slurm easier. In such a case, the scheduler would need to have a flexible mechanism to read and process the outputs of the results once they are finished.
I would like a way to schedule all of the calculations in slurm, via the central python script. Importantly, I need to be able to keep track of the status of the calculations, because as soon as one has finished, the results must be processed by the main python script and written to a database. What python library to use for this case? It would need to manage submissions and track the results.
Approaches tried / researched
multiprocessing
The first approach I took was to use the multiprocessing library. The main python script is scheduled with slurm and has N cores allocated to it. Each call to the python function is then run on a separate process like this:
from multiprocessing import Pool
with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
    results = pool.starmap(run_vasp, inputs)

This approach does work but does not use slurm for scheduling the calculations so I am not sure it is the best/most natural option. I need to select the number of processes to run in parallel. As it is written the results are not processed as soon as they are over but this should not be an issue.
Python libraries
I have not tried these yet, but I suspect they may not work for what I am looking for
pyslurm
This could be used to submit slurm jobs but I would need to create a class around it to monitor job status and retrieve the results.
Dask
This could work but I have read that it does not perform well for long jobs.
snakemake
This is too complex for what I am trying to do at the moment I think. From my understanding the workflow is configured with snakemake's own language and I would want everything to be handled in python.
However moving to a workflow manager may be something I would use in the future.

Have you read the top of here because it seems slurm should work well with mpi? It seems what you are looking to do is use slurm to connect to post-processing like 'Deep workflows' described here? It sounds like what you are looking for is meta-scheduler for slurm like DAGMan (Directed Acyclic Graph Manager) is a meta-scheduler for HTCondor? I do note at the bottom of ...

 there they mention sdag as being like DAGMan. Also since you mention focusing on Python, have you seen Submitit? ... Anyway.... Originally, I saw this because you mention considering Snakemake use. Looking it what you describe aside from the mpi use, I'd say it isn't too complex for Snakemake. (And even the mpi use doesn't make it too complex because you say, ...

  "All calculations are independent all may run on different a number of cores.") (And Snakemake does integrate with Slurm.) But what really caught my eye was the statement "the workflow is configured with snakemake's own language and I would want everything to be handled in python." You may not know it but Snakemake is a superset of Python. "The Snakefile is a superset of Python. Everything that is not a Snakemake rule should be valid Python." ...

 (SOURCE: from Parallel Programming in Python: Snakemake) And while it does have its own syntax for directives and rules, it integrates particularly well with Python because it is a superset. Unlike Nextflow, which is common alternative to Snakemake. The Snakefiles themselves I edit as .py in my code editor and later remove the extension. You don't need to know Python to use Snakemake; however, knowing Python makes it much easier for you to quickly become a Snakemake power user ...

 because you have the ability to use Python almost as much you'd like and the syntax and approaches are Pythonic.  I've not heard anything about long tasks being an issue for Snakemake but personally I haven't exceeded more than a few hours running with Snakemake.

Hi @Wayne, first thank you for all the suggestions.
The first suggestion relies on setting up a batch script for all calculations. This approach is completely outside of python so would not be suitable.
The second could be of interest since it deals with post-processing, but again this is outside of python.
The third suggestion looks very promising and I will look into that now and let you know. Basically submitting tasks and retrieving results from a central python script is really what I am looking for.

Snakemake can be like that central Python script, but better, with a little more effort to learn it. For example, you can run it again and if you added a new input file, it will only re-run the pipeline to make the output for that input and not re-run all the tasks again. It has a lot of features baked in that you'd otherwise want to add to your controlling Python script.

Finally for snakemake thanks for the clarification. The only issue I see is that it is a workflow manager and my script would need to be centered around snakemake. By this I mean that I need to set up and run a workflow with snakemake, rather than just running a python script. What I need at the moment is a tool to submit tasks to slurm and check results. I will move towards a proper workflow tool afterwards.
However I be completely wrong and have misunderstood how to use it.

To answer your comment between my two last ones.
That makes a lot of sense, but as you say I need to invest time in learning snakemake, which I am not looking to do at the moment basically. But I imagine that it is a tool that would be very useful for what I am doing.

I should highlight that Carpentry tutorial 'Parallel Programming in Python: Snakemake' is a good way to get started.

Great, thank you Wayne.
